# Securing Twitter Webhook

Tags: node.js, twitter, webhooks, koa

As mentioned in [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/securing-webhooks.html) 
Steps to validate a request

1. Create a hash using your consumer secret and incoming payload body.
2. Compare created hash with the base64 encoded x-twitter-webhooks-signature value.

Here is my code for doing so:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body))
const expectedHash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET).update(buffer).digest('base64')
```

The `x-twitter-webhooks-signature` header from twitter and the hash generated does not match. Also, the post at https://twittercommunity.com/t/validating-the-webhook-signature-header-in-node-js/102525 says that it's `JSON.stringify()` issue. I'm using koa and koa-body, how can I fix the hash mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Used `koa-bodyparser` instead of `koa-body` then `sha256` of `ctx.request.rawBody` matches with the header.